# Zend - Jquery Post values can't find ..?

Tags: jquery, ajax, zend-framework

Overflowers':

I'm using Zend, and doing an Ajax post to a controller. I can determine in the
Controller if it is a Ajax call using isXmlHttpRequest()..

However.. I can't find the value for my Posted JSON encoded data any where ?

I guess Zend strips it out, but its frustrating .. anyone have any idea where
the Ajax posted values go?

-Patrick.

```
data[0]='bob';
    data[1]='bob1';
    data[2]='bob2';
    tstring=$.toJSON(data);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost/rr/test/post",
        data: tstring,
        async: false,
        success: function(msg){
            alert( "Returned:" + msg+ "end" );
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my advice

[Serializing to JSON in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

your solution

[Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/serialize-form-to-json-with-jquery)